# Kerberos authentication failing with spark-submit command

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark, jdbc, kerberos

So I'm developing a Spring Batch engine. There are about 5 processes that are running and they get triggered by passing in a particular command line argument. For 4 of these 5 process I am running a java -jar command. For the 5th process I am using a spark-submit command as this process needs to leverage spark because of the size of the data being processed. I am running into issues with JDBC and Kerberos Authnetication with the spark-submit command. The Oracle @Configuration is the same for all of these processes. It works fine and authenticates fine with a java -jar command. But the moment I run a spark-submit command I get the below error...

```
Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Server not found in Kerberos database (7))
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:770) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:248) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.krb5.KrbException: Server not found in Kerberos database (7)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:70) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.getReply(KrbTgsReq.java:251) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.sendAndGetCreds(KrbTgsReq.java:262) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Credentials.java:458) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:693) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.krb5.Asn1Exception: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCRep.init(KDCRep.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.init(TGSRep.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.<init>(TGSRep.java:60) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
        ... 91 common frames omitted
```

My spark submit command is as follows...

```
spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true" --conf "spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-DSPARK_LOG=/home/${USERID}/payfloat_sim_input_log.spark -Dlog4j.configuration=file:${CEMS_COMMON_CFG}/log4jSpark.properties" --conf spark.ui.port=${SP_UI_PORT} --conf spark.hadoop.mapred.output.compress=${MAPRED_OUTPUT_COMPRESS} --master ${MASTER_TYPE} --deploy-mode ${DEPLOY_MODE} --queue ${SPARK_QUEUE} --executor-cores ${EXECUTOR_CORES} --num-executors ${NUM_EXECUTORS} --executor-memory ${EXECUTOR_MEMORY} ${AEGIS_INCLEARING_JAR} LoadTrialBalanceFile
```

Comment: What are `${MASTER_TYPE}` and `${DEPLOY_MODE}`? For starters, does the Kerberos auth work in local mode, or not? For non-local mode, how do you set up your Kerberos creds in the (remote) executors? Are you aware that the Hadoop libs override the default Java security settings for Kerberos - and that Spark uses these libs?

Comment: Also, for non-local mode, how do you set up your Kerberos client conf i.e. `/etc/krb5.conf` and are your executors running on nodes with canonical DNS names (cf. `Server not found in Kerberos database`)

Comment: So I was able to get this error to work. I had to specifically call out my kerberos files using --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/home/cemsctd/krb5.conf" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/home/cemsctd/krb5.conf"

Comment: That's the kerberos information for my Oracle Configuration. But for Hadoop, it's different. And Spring needs to instantiate those Beans so on startup it needs to configure the Oracle Configuration. But now, in my code, creating my Spark Session, I am getting errors: 20/07/22 21:43:28 WARN Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server has invalid Kerberos principal: rm/bdtcstr124n6.svr.us.jpmchase.net@EXCHAD.JPMCHASE.NET

Comment: That's the Kerberos SPN of a YARN ResourceManager service running inside JP MorganChase, I guess... Not an Oracle instance at all.

Comment: Again: Are you aware that the Hadoop libs override the default Java security settings for Kerberos - and that Spark uses these libs? And also, it seems your Spring stuff also messes with the Kerberos config, preventing Spark from launching the executors in YARN.

Comment: Bottom line: you cannot setup the kerberized Oracle connection before Spark is finished with its own kerberized Hadoop connection. Game over. Try something else, without Hadoop in the way.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Going to take some steps backwards to clean up this design. Thanks :)